# How can I search data from firebase using searchview in android studio?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I want to create query, for example when enter the 15 number from the keywords in the searchView,I want to show only first cardView in the recyclerview.I searched but ı can't find useful solutions.
Can anyone help me ? How Can ı fix this ? I am using firebase firestore database.
[here is my android studio code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cfkwp.png)
[here is firebase database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/93aQs.png)

Comment: If you understand Java, I think that this [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-filter-firestore-data-cheaper-705f5efec444) will help.

Comment: I solve it , thank you for your response Alex Mamo

Comment: Good to hear that, Esat ;)